# How to install numpy+mkl for python 2.7 on windows 64 bit?

Tags: python, numpy

I've already installed numpy 1.9.0 in Python.Now what should I do to get numpy+mkl?

Comment: If the 1.9 is not a strict requirement, and higher version allowed, I would suggest downloading the wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and install it using `pip` for example. For me - it was the simplest way to install all needed packages on x64 win 7 without setting up additional things like Anaconda.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you do not have an entire Python distribution or you do not want to install one, you can download and install a compiled `whl` package from [Christoph Gohlke's webpage](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). This `whl` contains `numpy` and is linked against `mkl`. When installing this package, you install both: `numpy` with the `mkl` dependencies.

All you have to do is:

- download the correct `whl` file (Choose the right Python version and 32/64 file)
- open a Windows cli with `Windows+R` and by running inside `cmd`
- go to the directory where you have downloaded the `whl` file, with `cd` instructions
- run `pip install numpy‑1.XX.Y+mkl‑cp3X‑cp3Xm‑win_amd64.whl`

For example, the command can be

```
pip install numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
```

You can do it for any package with some code that has to be compiled

Comment: Agree, this was the only way I've got it installed without any "magic" required.

Comment: Does anyone know how to change where the MKL libraries are installed? It seems they're going to a dir where I don't have access privileges, and I keep with a basic numpy, no mkl.

Comment: You can use `--user` flag to install it in a folder with your permission rights

Comment: What do you mean --user flag. Where to add this.

Comment: Anyways your solution doesn't work. I still do not have MKL installed just numpy. Access is denied for something that contains multiarray.py

Comment: Why do I need to manually download this specific whl when every other module works fine be default? Maybe this should be it's own question, but just find it very inconsistent.

Comment: @Annan Because the default version is not linked against library mkl that ensures great performance

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot Why is there not two versons? Or why is the default not the one with great performance? I notice there's a module called numpy-mkl but it seems to be out of date. ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-mkl )

Comment: Gholke's page is not up anymore

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install an entire Python distribution with lots of included packages, such as numpy and mkl. I would suggest the Anaconda Python distribution, https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 0):

> The above answer does great (+1) and brought me on the right track, but to
>   clear things up even more:

1. You can download the `.whl` from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
2. For choosing the right `.whl` you need to know numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp**XX**‑cp**XX**m‑win_amd64.whl
   where the **XX** are actually your python version (e.g. 36 for python version 3.6.x)
3. Do `pip install numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp**XX**‑cp**XX**m‑win_amd64.whl` in your cmd window and the place where you did download the `.whl` into