# pywin32 requirement is not satisfied after installing pypiwin32

Tags: python, pip, pywin32

Trying to install `pyad` package for Python 2.7.13 (windows x64) using `pip`.
There is `pywin32` package among requirements, so we get an error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pyad
Collecting pyad
Using cached pyad-0.5.16.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyad)
Collecting pywin32 (from pyad)
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from pyad) (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for pywin32 (from pyad)
```

Then I install `pypiwin32` which used to work in such cases:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-219-cp27-none-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pypiwin32
Successfully installed pypiwin32-219
```

But after this I still can't install `pyad` with the same error as above, like `pypiwin32` has never been installed:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pyad
Collecting pyad
Using cached pyad-0.5.16.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyad)
Collecting pywin32 (from pyad)
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from pyad) (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for pywin32 (from pyad)
```

Folder `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32` exists, the `pypiwin32` package seems to be installed.

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are facing `pywin32` installation problem, which is a binary wheel.

You can download binary wheels of `pywin32` [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32). You install it with

```
pip install pywin32-221-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

if it is the file you have downloaded

Select the correct version with respect to your installation (Python version and 32/64 bit Python version)

You can have detailed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217793/how-to-install-numpymkl-for-python-2-7-on-windows-64-bit/41218000#41218000)

Comment: I know, that I can get it from binary, but I wish I could do it using pip, for easier maintanance in future :)

Comment: Not for windows

Answer (score 2):

`pyad` is declaring it needs "the `pywin32` **distribution** package" in order to be installed. Distribution packages, i.e. something from PyPI that you can `pip install`, differ from Python packages, folders with an `__init__.py` that can be imported. The naming is confusing.

So, because it's not installed, it *tries* to install `pywin32`, but it can't find a distribution that matches your Python environment: Python 2.7 on Windows x64. On PyPI it appears like the only distributions are for Python 3.6: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/220

Comment: Versin #219 is being obtained using `pip`. As I can see, there is actually distrution for 2.7 on Windows x64: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/219

Comment: pypiwin32 is not pywin32. One has an extra "pi". They are listed separately.

Comment: I know, that `pypiwin32` is not `pywin32`. Though it's supposed to be a replacement. Meantime `pyad` should accept this way, according to readme on GitHub: https://github.com/zakird/pyad